# laravel 4.1 storing URL parameter, is it possible?

Tags: php, laravel-4, url-parameters

I'm still a student and still new with these frameworks

so I have two controllers in my routes:

```
Route::resource('homeworks', 'HomeworkController');
Route::resource('submithomeworks', 'SubmithomeworkController');
```

in views/Homework/show.blade.php, I have:

```
href="{{ URL::action('submithomeworks.create', $homeworks->id) }}"
```

so the URL will go from

```
http://localhost:8000/homeworks/1
```

to

```
http://localhost:8000/submithomeworks/create?1
```

so is there a way I can just store `$homework->id` which is just `1` in this situation to the `submithomeworks` table?

I tried this on the `SubmithomeworksController`

```
public function store()
{
    $rules = array(
        'homework_id'       => 'required',
        'homework_body'     => 'required'

    );

    $submithomework = new Submithomework;
    $submithomework->homework_id        = Input::get('homework_id');
    $submithomework->homework_body      = Input::get('homework_body');
    $submithomework->student_id         = Auth::user()->id;
    $submithomework->save();

    Session::flash('message', 'Homework successfully added.');
    return Redirect::to('homeworks');

}
```

but what do I do after that in the view? it won't store the `homework_id` says its still `NULL`

Answer (score 0):

If you need to access a route parameter you can use the `Route` facade. For example:

```
Route::input('id');
```

You can check the [Laravel Docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.1/routing#route-parameters).

Comment: so i put this in my `Routes`? i just want `$homework_id` from `{{ URL::action('submithomeworks.create', $homeworks->id) }}` URL to be seen in the `SubmithomeworksController` and store it inside `homework_id` in `Submithomeworks` well i can always do a long SQL query but that's my last resort because i don't think my instructor would want that